# Mosfet as a Switch

Tags: mosfet, ac, altium

I have created 2 circuits using altium designer as shown below:

[image: Circuit]

After simulation here is what i have for the left circuit: [image]

Right circuit:[image]

Basically, as you can see in the first circuit i have 2 pulse sources, 1 gives +15V and the other gives -15V. The goal for the second circuit is to use only one pulse while obtaining the same function. I am using mosfets in saturation for this, however, as you can cleary see in the simulation, only the +15V gets through. Any suggestions?

Comment: You must apply gate signals between gate and source pins of the MOSFETs. Your pulses in the first circuit are not with respect to the source pins. And remember that, switching a MOSFET in real life requires a driving interface. By the way, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to pass the VSIN to the 82 ohm resistor for load testing purposes only when there is a pulse signal. If the pulse signal is off, then even if there is a VSIN, no current should pass through to the 82 ohm resistor. As you can see for the left circuit, it works, but the second one it doesn't

Comment: What is the amplitude of V1 in the 2nd circuit? Is it 3.3V? Have to tried changing it?

Comment: Maybe use a relay until you are ready to go with mosfets?